# Embedding youtube channel in mobile pages

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

Embedding single youtube videos in mobile pages isn't a challange thanks to el goog, but embedding a channel into a mobile page still is a mystery to me.
The problem is the screen width. I've tried to concoct a javascript code for this, but my knowledge of JS is a bit non-existent...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sWidth = screen.width;
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/youtube.xml&up_channel=Autovaros&synd=open&w=" + sWidth + "&h=390&title=&border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&output=js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
```

The result is -as you you can guess- nothing... but I hope the concept goes through...
Any help would be most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this link below. It includes two files, a css and .js file and allows for a channel to play in a player. Also written in good ol'jquery. Just replace the two URL links to your corresponding links and try it out.

http://code.google.com/p/jq-youtube-player/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc